# Trigger build on Jenkins from Github repo

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've found many sites that describe how to trigger a build on a Jenkins machine whenever new code is pushed to a Github repository.  One thing that keeps showing up repeatedly is to check the "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" item under the Build Triggers section..

[image]

Unfortunately, no matter what I do I can't seem to get that item to show up as an option for me under Build Triggers.

[image]

I've even removed and re-installed Jenkins from scratch.  When I install it, I just tell it to install all of the most common plugins.  I've verified in the Jenkins configuration that the GitHub plugin is there.

[image]

What am I missing to trigger a build on a GitHub repo update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-PluginInformation this was changed from

```
Build when a change is pushed to GitHub
```

to

```
GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling
```

So it is sufficient to have GitHub Plugin installed.

Comment: Well, don't i feel like the idiot. I actually read that section on the github plugin page but totally ignored that big huge yellow box staring me in the face saying exactly that.....the name changed.  Thanks for taking the time to point me to the obvious.